# Internet Explorer browser did not support my machine?

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer

I am using IE browser version 8, but I want use IE10 or IE11,so I had downloaded IE10 and IE11, but did not support my machine.

This is my system properties.

- Operating System: Windows 7 ultimate
- processor: AMD Athlon(tm)IIx2 255 processor 3.10ghz
- Installed memory (RAM):4.00 GB
- System type:64-bit operating system

So how can I install the IE10 and IE11 browser.

Thanks for advance....

Comment: what do you mean "Did not support my machine"? Where are you downloading it from?

Comment: This is my downloaded link.http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/internet-explorer/ie-10-worldwide-languages and then select the 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Please post screenshots of your system info (Win+Break or Control Panel → System) and of any error messages you receive. You probably cannot embed pictures, so just link them.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to check to make sure you have service pack 1 for windows 7 installed. I think you need that installed before  the later versions of internet explorer will go on.

Comment: Indeed. [Here’s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321440.aspx) a more detailed explanation of what’s required. [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822351.aspx) is the same page for IE10.

Comment: its really i had many times download and install always display your system is not supported format.

Comment: To upgrade your IE you must have the prerequisites installed before IE will install successfully.

Comment: @thiru List of prerequisites: [IE 10](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818833/en-us) / [IE 11](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2847882/en-us)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20  This will allow your system to check to see if it is ready to update to Service pack 1. Once that is all done you should be able to then install ie 10 and/or ie 11